# Drupal commerce and commerce_paypal puts 2 paypal icons in the payment method radio buttons list

Tags: paypal, drupal-7, commerce

I'm a drupal developer with years of experience building big complex drupal sites.  In all my time working with drupal however, I've never been tasked with building an ecommerce enabled site.  I'm now working up a commerce site using drupal 7 with drupal commerce and the commerce_paypal module.  I've read all the docs and I've configured products and added a payment rule that selects paypal express as the payment method.  That's the only payment rule that I have set up.  BUT when I reach the point in the checkout where I need to select my payment method, I see 2 paypal icons.  They are visually identical, but their behavior is different.  If I choose the first one, all goes as it should.  Payment is made and the seller paypal account is updated with the purchase amount.  If I choose the 2nd one (which shouldn't be there at all) then I get an error message saying that paypal express is not configured correctly.  Can someone who is more familiar with drupal commerce and commerce_paypal offer any insight into why there are 2 paypal options (suggesting that I have 2 payment methods configured, but as I wrote earlier, I only have 1) and how I can get rid of the broken one?

Thanks for any assistance!
a

Comment: i believe ur paypal payment gateway got imported twice in hook_payment_gate_way_info(check if u have 2 rules for the same paypal gateway in ur configuration->rules)

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response.  I'm afraid that's not the cause of this issue.  As I mentioned in the original post, I only have the one payment rule.  I have noticed though, that if I disable that rule, the "ghost" paypal icon -- the one that if chosen for payment method returns an error saying that paypal express is not configured -- is still there.  Any ideas?  Thanks again!